# Get H1 tag content and favicon from a URL with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

the screenshot below is of a custom wordpress theme I developing.

http://gyazo.com/0646a8cafa6a70e8dcb6a3f41b5bb8a7

I want to find out how to echo the contents of the H1 tag and favicon url into each post with only a URL to an articles page.  For example if I used this URL:
http://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-design-a-billion-dollar-company-2014-9

I would be able to get the follow data:
How To Design A Billion-Dollar Company
http://static5.businessinsider.com/assets/images/faviconBI.ico

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For grabbing the H1:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com/some/article"); //Site you want to search
foreach ($html->find("h1") as $part)
{
    $h1 = $part->innertext; //Setting the h1 tag to $h1 var
    break; //only want to do this for the first H1 we so so break
}
```

For grabbing the Favicon, read this tutorial:
[Grabbing a Favicon from External website](http://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Get-Favicon-From-Web-Site-Link-Access-External-Files)

Comment: From what I can find online, I think it's worth mentioning that `file_get_html` is a function provided through a [third party library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It doesn't look to be a standard part of the language, at least as far as [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/) is showing me.

Comment: Perhaps attempt to use file_get_contents() ? Similar to the way that the code gets the favicon.